# codeigniter get returned data variable from model in controller and use it in conditional statement

Tags: codeigniter

what is wrong with my search implementation, here what i wish to achieve.

view page(form) -> controller(form data variable) -> model(query database and pass to controller)  if there's a result  return TRUE else return FALSE -> controller(get data from model) if true display data in table else if FALSE display a no results returned message.

here are my pages:

```
view:  
<form action="<?php echo site_url('retrieve')?>" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="id">  
.... 
</form>


model:
public function retrieve($id)
{

$search = "SELECT *  FROM table";
    $result = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($search);
    $result->execute();     

    if($result->rowCount()>0){
    return  $query_result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}  

controller:  
public function retrieve_info()
{
   $id = $this->input->post('id'),

   $this->load->model('search_model');
   $this->search_model->retrieve($id);      
   $data['query_result'] = $this->search_model->retrieve($id);    
   $this->load->view('display',$data);          

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the form action is linking to the retrieve function in the controller.  However, from your example there is no retrieve function in your controller, only in your model.

view:

```
 <form action="<?php echo site_url('retrieve')?>" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="id">  
    .... 
    </form>
```

model:

```
public function retrieve($id)
{

$search = "SELECT *  FROM table";
    $result = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($search);
    $result->execute();     

    if($result->rowCount()>0){
    return  $query_result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

controller:

```
public function retrieve()
{

   if($_POST){
       $id = $this->input->post('id'),

      $this->load->model('search_model');      
      $data['query_result'] = $this->search_model->retrieve($id);    
      $this->load->view('display',$data);          
   }else {
     //form failed to submit via post
   }

}
```